# How to LESS classes in a Wordpress CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, less

I'm wondering how to group or LESS classes in a wordpress CSS, for instance, I have alot more of pages to add the following style, and it's very time consuming having to copy and paste the end parts of the classes:

```
.page-id-16592 .header_bottom, 
.page-id-16663 .header_bottom, 
.page-id-16664 .header_bottom, 
.page-id-16665 .header_bottom, 
.page-id-16666 .header_bottom,
.page-id-16601 .header_bottom,
.postid-16728 .header_bottom,
.postid-16722 .header_bottom,
.postid-16725 .header_bottom,
.postid-16727 .header_bottom {
    background-color: #222 !important;
}
```

I have tried to do the following with no luck:

```
.page-id-16592, .page-id-16663, 
.page-id-16664, .page-id-16665, 
.page-id-16666, .page-id-16601, 
.postid-16728, .postid-16722, 
.postid-16725, .postid-16727 {
    .header_bottom {
        background-color: #222 !important;
    }
}
```

This allows me to add the page ids efficiently.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Assuming there is some commonality between those pages for you to be targetting them specifically - you could use PHP to add a class to the `body` tag for those pages, and then target just the one class.

Comment: I couldn't find any commonalities between those pages, they are just normal pages that I'd like to present to a different group of audiences

Comment: Okay. Then you'll just need to track their IDs, or add some meta data to each page, and use that to identify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following, or similar, code to your `functions.php` file. This will then add a class to the `<body>` tag for the page, when post ID is in the `$ids` array.

Alternatively you could modify this to target post/pages with specific custom meta attributes, or categories, etc.

```
add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
    // Prepare your target ids
    $ids = [16592, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 16601, 16728, 16722, 16725, 16727];

    if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $ids)) {
        $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';
    }

    return $classes;
});
```

Then in your CSS, you can target those specific pages using:

```
.my-custom-class .header_bottom {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This looks like an awesome solution. Does it apply to .page-id-xxx as well as .postid-xxx?

Comment: `get_the_ID()` will get the current post/page ID. So if the ID is in the array, it'll work.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work. When I add the code in functions.php, the page-id classes disappear.

Comment: #fail. I forgot to return the `$classes`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you apply a class on all posts/pages you would like to style?

Something generic like `.main`

```
.main .header_bottom {
    background-color: #222 !important;
}
```

or if you don't mind applying this style across all `.header_bottom` then simply

```
.header_bottom {
    background-color: #222 !important;
}
```

Comment: I'd only like to apply to certain pages, therefore I can't apply it to a generic class.